# jquery validate digits backwards (123456 and 654321)

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

good morning,

i need a guide for use a function to jquery validate where user write digits backwards.

Example:

user write: 123456.
the system validate that write backwards: 654321.

i think use Jquery validate personalize function.

```
$.(#myform).validate({

});
```

thanks!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? And why haven't you accepted any answers so far?

Comment: and what makes '123456' "backwards"? Your question is very unclear. Given you've been a member for over a year, you should know what's expected of questions here.

Comment: var a = new String(number), b = '', i; for(i=a.length-1;i>=0;--i) { b += a.charAt(i); }

Or did you mean something different?

Comment: What are you validating the user's input against?  Are you showing them a string and asking them to type it in backwards, like a captcha?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `.reverse` for strings, but there is one for arrays, so:

```
"123456".split("").reverse().join(""); // "654321"
```

And then simply check whether that string matches the user's input. I don't know the validation plugin but you can simply use the `===` operator.

Comment: @fireflx: I think you could accept some answers if they helped you.